# python selenium accessing more than one of popup window pages

Tags: python, selenium

When i click "Wax Cloud Wallet" button opening a login window page. But login window page opens a new login page. How can i access second of window? [windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KwK5z.png)

Answer (score 0):

switch to the login window by this

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

after typing username, password and login successfully switch back to original window again

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```